# How to make a column that describes another Column in toad point SQL

Tags: sql

I am working on a small piece of code that looks at banking loans. What I want to do is look at the letters of the loan and get a description of it. Here is an example:

```
Select Loan, Replace(Replace(Replace(Loan, '3',''), '2',''),'1','') AS 
[Description] 
From Banking_Data 

 Loan     Description  
 123BL        BL       
 321CC        CC
```

This is what I need.

```
 Loan     Description   Type
 123BL        BL        Business
 321CC        CC        Credit Card
```

So far I have done the process of only to get the Description but I am stuck on getting the type. Any ideas in toad point?

Comment: Where do you find the Business and Credit Card information?

Comment: I have to fill it out myself there is no data on Type.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is your input? Only column `Loan`? Is it always enough to look at the last two letters?

Comment: I added a updated version if this helps I am sorry for the confusion still new to SQL and trying to get a quick grasp of it.